# Find difference in two table column values in mysql and mssql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have two databases primary/parent database is in Mysql (with PHP) and child database is in Mssql (with .Net). Both databases are of same structure and contains same data. My requirement is when any record in parent database updated then it will update the same record in child database. In other means data syncing in parent and child databases. Only want to do it via Mysql and PHP. Can some one help me out. Thanks in advance for any help.

Update:- I don't want to use trigger as well.
.Net application has some advanced functionality as well, so there is difference in number of tables, mssql database has some more tables than mysql database. But the matched tables have same structure as in parent database.

Comment: why can't you use one database for both PHP Mysql & .Net.

Comment: if you don't show what you've tried so far, as well as a database schema i doubt you'll get help.

Comment: @xanadev .Net application has some advanced functionality as well, so there is difference in number of tables, mssql database has some more tables than mysql database.

Comment: @xanadev I have searched a lot but nothing found to be useful which can help me. Is there any thing you can suggest?

Comment: well then you shouldn't say _Both databases are of same structure_, i would assume that you are using the same Schema, well then include the structure of the tables that are used on both sides.

Comment: @xanadev structure e.g. table A has id(int), name(varchar), description(text), created(timestamp). Same table and structure in both databases.

Comment: I do not want to use triggers. Database has large number of records.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173063/discussion-between-xanadev-and-m-bains).